# Detecting run-time game platform in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, detection, platform

I'm working on a C# XNA project that requires me to display information based on the platform the game is on.

Is there a way to detect the platform (XBox, Windows, Zune) during run-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88.aspx) is what you want. Per the MSDN doc, you would use it like:

```
 OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
 PlatformID pid = os.Platform;
 switch (pid) 
 {
   //Do whatever
 }
```

Comment: didn't thought that it can be a non-XNA related solution =D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Environment.OSVersion` to obtain information on the Platform and Version. The Platform property will likely tell you what you want, although I don't know for sure if the returned strings will be enough to tell the different platforms apart. I'd be surprised if they didn't though.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to check the preprocessor flags

```
#if WINDOWS
// do stuff
#endif

#if XBOX360
// do stuff
#endif

##if ZUNE
// do stuff
##endif
```